# custom function as DRF SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do you define a separate function that acts as a model seralizer on a django model instance? (not a SerializerMethodField)

```
def function_a(model):
    ...
    return [{'a1': ... } , {'a2': ... } ... ]

class ExampleSeralizer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    field_A = serializers.???('function_a') 

    class Meta:
        model = models.ModelA
        fields = ['field_A']
```

Comment: What is the goal ? a computed field ?

Comment: What does your `function_a` returns?

Comment: A dictionary that's populated from model instance values formatted in a specific way (e.g. datetime formatted to yyyy/mm/dd). This is kept separate from the model seralizer as there it needs to support different formats in the future (e.g. function_a where dates are yyyy/mm/dd, function_b where dates are yyyy/mm) etc